# How does Spring map Docker environment variables?

Tags: spring, docker, docker-compose

So I found [this sample project](https://github.com/jonashackt/cxf-spring-cloud-netflix-docker/tree/4a8f578c2900fed1ef8952c9dba7c8e81aa621a7). In [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/jonashackt/cxf-spring-cloud-netflix-docker/blob/4a8f578c2900fed1ef8952c9dba7c8e81aa621a7/docker-compose.yml) I notice that he is supplying a environment variable called `REGISTRY_HOST`, and that this is then used in various `application.yml` files in the project, [here for instance](https://github.com/jonashackt/cxf-spring-cloud-netflix-docker/blob/6a26654034b289ea8593422e274399e30bfdd60c/weatherbackend/src/main/resources/application.yml).

What I am wondering is, how does this mapping work and is it Docker or Spring that performs the magic? For instance, he is binding `registry.host` and `registry.port`, but how exactly is this mapped? How come it is `registry` that is the prefix, and where does `registry.host` come from when it isn't in the compose file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what docker does is it just assigns the environment variable, nothing more. But on Spring side, it reads this variables and tries to assign to an application property. Which is explained in [Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) Please see the [24.7.2 Relaxed Binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding) part of the documentation.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for! Any idea where the `registry.host` portion comes from? Is it Docker that is smart enough to give this a default even when left out, or is Spring simply falling back to `localhost` because `registry.host` is empty?

Comment: Nevermind that additional question, `registry.host` value is `eureka-serviceregistry`.

Comment: I think it uses `registry.host` as specific for this application. And if you look at the yaml file, you can see that `${registry.host:localhost}` which states, try to look for variable `registry.host` if you can not find it assign `localhost` as the default value. Same for the `registry.port` as well. Colon character `:` does the the default value setting.